# バグ:説明文中のbold(ボールド、太字)が反映されていない

Tags: バグ, 完了, markdown

文中に
**太字**
とすべきところが
**太字**
になっているところがあります。

確認した場所:

- ヘルプ -> ツアー
- 書式設定の方法

Comment: 現在開発者が取り込み中です。ポストでは直していますが、コメントやツアー等は後ちょっと時間かかります。

Comment: @jmac `status-completed` になっているのですが，たまたま[ツアー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)を見ていたら，`&lt;b&gt;クローズ（閉鎖）&lt;/b&gt;` と `**編集**` が目に入ったので，ご報告だけ．（[ツアーページにMarkdownが正しく機能していない部分があります](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1412/)も関係していそう？）