# コメント欄でMarkdownの太字(bold)が反映されないケースがある

Tags: バグ, 調査中, markdown, コメント

コメント欄でMarkdownの**太字**を使用する際、特定の文字に隣接していると反映されないケースがあるようです。
具体的には`「`　`」`の隣りに空白を開けずに`**`を使用すると、Markdownが反映されず記号がそのまま表示されてしまいます。

なお、「ツアーページ」の表示でも同じ問題が起きているようです。
一方で、質問や回答の本文では問題無く投稿できています。

[ツアーページでの表示結果](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)
[image: ツアーページでの表示結果]
[ja.traducir.winでの翻訳](https://ja.traducir.win/)
[image: ja.traducir.winでの翻訳]

関連メタのやり取りを見てみると、日本語の場合は全角カッコの類に(空白を空けず)文字が隣接しているとNGなようです。

関連：
[バグ:説明文中のbold(ボールド、太字)が反映されていない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/156/3060)
[ツアーページにMarkdownが正しく機能していない部分があります](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1412/3060)

Comment: CommonMark 準拠するなら、確かにこれはバグです (参考1: [CommonMark 0.28 の仕様](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#emphasis-and-strong-emphasis)、参考2: [babelmark2 でのテスト](https://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%80%8C**%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88**%E3%80%8D%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88))。サイトで使われている Markdown エンジンは [MarkdownSharp](https://github.com/StackExchange/MarkdownSharp) というもの[らしい](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network/10370#10370)ので、これを直すという話になりそうです。

Comment: [Meta Stack Exchange での議論](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238957/341401)によると「CommonMark 準拠になるようエンジンを改変することもできるが、互換性破壊の影響を無視できないので簡単な作業ではない」とのことです。このため、これがバグなのか仕様なのかは判断が難しいと思っています。(鉤括弧はパンクチュエーション記号なので特別扱いする理由になりえます。)

Comment: 通常の投稿では大丈夫なようです。コメント欄はともかく、ツアーページなどでもレンダリング結果が異なるのは不思議ですね。

Comment: あ、なるほど、通常の投稿では使えるのですね。調べてみるとコメント欄だけで Markdown がバグるという事例は[過去あった](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69313/341401)ようなので、修正を促せるかもしれません。

Comment: これと類似の問題かもしれません: ["Problems with Markdown in Post Comments"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28967/341401)

Comment: 類似スレッドかもしれません: [Bolding broken after full-width punctuation marks (。？！ etc.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254006/bolding-broken-after-full-width-punctuation-marks-etc) ...そして、2019 年にもこのバグは残っているようです(先ほど遭遇しました)。

Comment: まだこの問題が発生しているようですので開発チームに転送します。